# add formula in vba - syntax error

Tags: vba, excel

im trying to record a macro. my formula in excel is:

`=IF(AND(OR(B2={"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15 ","16 "}),OR(J2={"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"})),CONCATENATE(J2," ",IF(K2="p","pre",""),"-"," ",IF(A2="",0,A2)),"")`

(this formula basically changes the names of my product according to quarter and type, while taking into consideration previous quarters )

note: once i record it. it looks like this in vba:

`Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(OR(RC[-6]={""1"",""2"",""3"",""4"",""5"",""6"",""7"",""8"",""9"",""10"",""11"",""12"",""13"",""14"",""15 "",""16 ""}),OR(RC[2]={""Q1"",""Q2"",""Q3"",""Q4""})),CONCATENATE(RC[2],"" "",IF(RC[3]=""p"",""pre"",""""),""-"","" "",IF("& _
        """",0,RC[-7])),"""")"`

and yet, it gives me a syntax error...whats wrong?!

thank you

Comment: what if you write it in one line, without concatenating formula text and without any `line continuation` with `_`?

Comment: It does that automatically

Comment: and i have a lot of macros with those and they all work fine

Comment: ok. I did wht u said....it works....lol.
thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF(A2="",0,A2)),"")` Is being converted to `IF(""",0,RC[-7])),"""")`

### Assuming that If your original formula is in `Range("H2")`

```
"=IF(AND(OR(RC[-6]={""1"",""2"",""3"",""4"",""5"",""6"",""7"",""8"",""9"",""10"",""11"",""12"",""13"",""14"",""15 "",""16 ""}),OR(RC[2]={""Q1"",""Q2"",""Q3"",""Q4""})),CONCATENATE(RC[2],"" "",IF(RC[3]=""p"",""pre"",""""),""-"","" "",IF(RC[-7]="""",0,RC[-7])),"""")"
```

### I don't see the need to surround number with quotes when using formula contants

```
"=IF(AND(OR(RC[-6]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16}),OR(RC[2]={""Q1"",""Q2"",""Q3"",""Q4""})),CONCATENATE(RC[2],"" "",IF(RC[3]=""p"",""pre"",""""),""-"","" "",IF(RC[-7]="""",0,RC[-7])),"""")"
```

### Don't start a line continuations in the middle of a double escape pattern `""""`. I prefer to place them between statements when possible

### The easiest way to convert a formula to `R1C1` notation is to use the Immediate Window

> ?Chr(34) & Replace(Range("H2").FormulaR1C1,chr(34),Chr(34) & Chr(34))  & Chr(34)

[image]

### Build and test your strings in the Immediate Window when possible.  It will complain when it is wrong

[image]

### You can even use create variables in the Immediate Window when writing concatenations

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that's wrong is the `"& _` part. It should be replaced by `RC[-7]=`. See the corrected line below.

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(OR(RC[-6]={""1"",""2"",""3"",""4"",""5"",""6"",""7"",""8"",""9"",""10"",""11"",""12"",""13"",""14"",""15 "",""16 ""}), OR(RC[2]={""Q1"",""Q2"",""Q3"",""Q4""})), CONCATENATE(RC[2],"" "",IF(RC[3]=""p"",""pre"",""""),""-"","" "",IF(RC[-7]="""",0,RC[-7])),"""")"
```